# check if require field are

Tags: html, forms, vuejs2

I try to force the validation of require in VueJs2. (without any form validation lib).

i have a field that display depending on if require element are filled. I can't find ou the good way to do this. I have sum up the situation in the code below (very simplified one)

```
<div>
    <form>
         <input required ...></input>
         <input ></input>
         <input required ...></input>
         <input required ...></input>
         <input ></input>

         <label v-if="allRequiredFieldHaveContent()"> All is fine</input>
         <label v-else >Some require input are empty</label>
```

I can't determine what to do in this allRequiredFieldHaveContent(). Any suggestion  please?

NB : I can Not put some v-model on those input for reasons...